# Why don't ferromomagnetic domains align with one another?

Tags: electromagnetism

When a ferromagnetic has never been placed in a magnetic field what is stopping the domains within it from aligning and forming a permanent magnet?

The reason I ask is because it seems that individual dipoles within domains align because it is energetically favourable, so it seems that it would be energetically favourable for domains to also align.

Comment: So, how do the domains get together and decide which direction to align to? Or, does each domain think it is the 'right' direction, and wait for everyone else to align with it? While it is energetically favorable for the ensemble to all align together, it takes an activation energy for a single domain to do something about it.

Comment: "Later, the quantum theory made it possible to understand the microscopic origin of the Weiss field. The exchange interaction between localized spins favored a parallel (in ferromagnets) or an anti-parallel (in anti-ferromagnets) state of neighboring magnetic moments"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain#Development_of_domain_theory . Domains are macroscopic and lose the advantage of the qm spin spin soutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite ok explained in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain#Why_domains_form)

Here I will just cite wiki:
The reason a piece of magnetic material such as iron spontaneously divides into separate domains, rather than exist in a state with magnetization in the same direction throughout the material, is to minimize its internal energy. A large region of ferromagnetic material with a constant magnetization throughout will create a large magnetic field extending into the space outside itself (diagram a, right). This requires a lot of magnetostatic energy stored in the field. To reduce this energy, the sample can split into two domains, with the magnetization in opposite directions in each domain (diagram b right). The magnetic field lines pass in loops in opposite directions through each domain, reducing the field outside the material. To reduce the field energy further, each of these domains can split also, resulting in smaller parallel domains with magnetization in alternating directions, with smaller amounts of field outside the material.
The domain structure of actual magnetic materials does not usually form by the process of large domains splitting into smaller ones as described here. When a sample is cooled below the Curie temperature, for example, the equilibrium domain configuration simply appears. But domains can split, and the description of domains splitting is often used to reveal the energy tradeoffs in domain formation.

This is easily checked with two bar magnets placed aside they will tend to stick North to south and south to north.

Comment: this is correct ,but should be expanded to become a clear explanation. you could quote from the link , even copy the figure.

Comment: In other words it **isn't** energetically favourable for domains to align. They will do so only when forced to by an external field.